# Php script for saving and retrieving session and cookie value

Tags: php, database

Been brain storming and researching to get 2 index file.php. One to save session and cookie value to database and the second one would call and echo the saved session and cookie value from database when user visits again. Anyone can help?

Comment: _“Anyone can help?”_ - you are asking way too unspecific. Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, the session value are store in `$_SESSION`, and `$_COOKIE` for cookie value. The process can be as simple as create one table that has column consist of userid, session and cookie value, and write your code to save into the table. After that in the next visit retrieve it from the table by the user id.

P.S.: Why you want to keep the session and cookie value in the database though? Take not ethat as long as the session or cookie value is not been deleted, the value will be there until the next visit.

Comment: Its a school project and challenge. I need to only store session user's ID to DB and retrieve back. Would have a TTL set for one week for users ID to expire or self disrupt. All pages ain't going to be calling DB to retrieve that session ID, a single page is what would have access to it and i also do know how to use $_SESSION and $_COOKIE in php header and call for it but my challenge is saving to DB and calling it back

Answer (score 0):

I found this on github and tried bit the session info was not saved to DB

[Session integration to DB](https://github.com/dominicklee/PHP-MySQL-Sessions)

But i was finally able to get what i was doing wrong with my php code. I was able to achieve the task using this in my corresponding php files

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['userId'];?>`$Id = $_SESSION['userId'];`$_SESSION['userId'] = $Id;`
```